# Parse XML Webservice response to appropriate type c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services

I've got a ASMX webservice that returns the following XML, which is a string array. How can I deserialize into the correct type?

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <string>0 Item(s)</string>
    <string>0</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

In JQuery this is easy, but I'm looking for a way to do it in C#.

Comment: Normally you'd add service reference via VS to do all for you... Since you seem to want to build it by hand - duplicate covers pretty much all options you have in .Net.